# Magento 1.7 database deadlock

Tags: magento

Magento 1.7 seems to happen lot of database deadlock causinf fatal error - during checkout, during indexing, during sitemap generation.

Like one examplw is if indexinf process is running, I can can not login as admin. It gives deadlock error.

What is good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 1.7 (whole magento) has several db related issue espicually for large database (lot of product).

There are some solutions already discussed here [Magento deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309341/magento-deadlocks)