# How to prevent table lock with MYSQL select with Innodb

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with a select statement that locks a table.
I have tried the "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;" thing, played with autocommit on off, etc., but it always locks the table.
They say Innodb uses row level locking, but I think the table gets scanned and it causes the whole table to be locked.

Query:

```
select  ID, RefNr 
from TRMSMain.tblcalldata  
where  (CallStarted BETWEEN '2014/06/13' AND '2014/06/13 23:59:59') 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 50
```

This shows me there is a lock on the table:

```
show open tables where in_use <> 0;
```

Is there any other way to prevent the select from locking the table?
I have googled and tried many things already.
Many thanks
Anton

Comment: Did you try `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`? 
This, I believe, will implicitly convert select statement locks using `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, allowing selects to be performed as a consistent, non-locking, read.

I don't really know if that would help, in your case, or not. I picked the suggestion up from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309341/magento-deadlocks).

Comment: I can't see why that select would set a lock (manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) "SELECT ... FROM is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and setting no locks unless the transaction isolation level is set to SERIALIZABLE. For SERIALIZABLE level, the search sets shared next-key locks on the index records it encounters. "